# Diagonal movement and animation in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to c# and am working on a top-down 2d adventure game. I have my player moving in 8 directions, and the animator working in the 4 main directions (N,E,S,W).

I am trying to set up the blend tree in the animator for the diagonal movements, but am having trouble setting this up.

Here is my script.

```
public void PlayerAnimation(float moveHorizontal, float moveVertical, Animator anim, Player_Manager _PMS){
// IF we are moving we set the animation IsMoving to true
if(moveHorizontal != 0 || moveVertical != 0){
anim.SetBool("IsMoving", true);
}else{
anim.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
}

// We are wanting to go in the positive X direction.
if(moveHorizontal > 0){
// IF we have invert X on we adjust a different animation.
if(_PMS.invertX){
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 2);
}else{
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 4);
}
// We are wanting to move in the negative X direction.
}else if(moveHorizontal < 0){
// IF we have invert X on we adjust a different animation.
if(_PMS.invertX){
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 4);
}else{
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 2);
}
// We are wanting to move in the negative Y direction.
}else if(moveVertical < 0){
// IF we have invert Y on we adjust a different animation.
if(_PMS.invertY){
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 1);
}else{
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 3);
}
}else if(moveVertical > 0){
// IF we have invert Y on we adjust a different animation.
if(_PMS.invertY){
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 3);
}else{
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 1);
}
}else if(moveHorizontal > 0 || moveVertical < 0){

if(_PMS.invertX || _PMS.invertY){
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 7);
}else{
anim.SetInteger("Direction", 5);
}

}
}
```

I am using the "and" operator to call both x and y axis for the SE movement (last statement), but it does not register when I set it up in the animator. Is there another way I am supposed to call the diagonal movements?

Comment: **never use else-if**.  you will never, ever, ever, get it to work.  rewrite with "breakaway" code http://stackoverflow.com/a/35224838/294884 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228676/avoiding-nested-blocks-with-asynchronous-code-in-objective-c/25228698#25228698

Comment: @JoeBlow, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: This code is completely unreadable....

Comment: Hi Austin .. dude there is THOUSANDS OF WORDS about it on the two "internet links" (look for the "blue color") in my comment just there dude - heh!  how much more could I write?

Comment: Hi @joeblow could you explain how I would write the statement for both x and y axis for a diagonal?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get it with the switch statement. thank you!!